# token only working once Retrofit2

Tags: java, authentication, android-studio, token, retrofit

I'm trying to use requests with token authentication, it works pretty well the first time, but the second time I try that I get 401 server error, even if I hardcore the token I get the same response that im addind spaces, but the same code is used for the first request that works fine and the second request which return a 401 error, here is my Service Code:

```
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {

        Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Token " + authToken)
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        };

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);
        httpClient.interceptors().add(logging);
        httpClient.interceptors().add(interceptor);

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

my server needs to receive, Token &$&%$&TGDHGDHFD3456436EXAMPLETOKEN as a header, I don't think the problem is on another place of the code because even if I hardcore the token I get the same problem.

Comment: Have you tested on server side if you receiving headers you are expecting?

Comment: im using django and dont really know hot to debug those things, but if i do the same thing on postman, i can do it more than once without a problem.

Comment: Here you can see how to setup logging levels for Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/

Answer (score 0):

You can send your Authorization as a parameter in each request in your interface. It will help you when you transfer from using basic Auth to OAuth2.

```
public interface createContact {
        @GET(Constants.RETROFIT_CONTACTS_PATH)
        @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
        Call<ArrayList<ProductsModel>> createContacts(@Header("Authorization") String user);
    }
```